# How can I change the linked version of boost in python homebrew?

Tags: python, boost, homebrew, mapnik

I'm trying to use mapnik with a python installation done by homebrew on my mac os x 10.8.3. Here is the problem:

```
otool -L $(brew list boost | grep 'python.*.dylib')
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

As you can see, it points to `/usr/local/opt/python`... which is totally wrong (this is the defailt python provided by apple, which I'm not intending to use).

How can I change this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I finally did it. Here is how:

I ran this comands:

```
brew rm $(brew deps mapnik --with-cairo)
brew rm mapnik
brew rm boost
brew update
brew doctor
brew install --with-icu --build-from-source boost
brew install mapnik --with-cairo
```

now, the command `otool -L $(brew list boost | grep 'python.*.dylib')` still shows this:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.53.0/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Here is the complete thread: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16144

Comment: When I do 'brew install --with-icu --build-from-source boost' the installation seams to run forever... According to the system monitor I have Clang abusing my mac... I am stuck with './b2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boos' in the terminal. Any way out?